# Stream removed error in Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that runs on the creation of a new user. The function typically fails on the first call after not being called for a while. I'm hoping someone could help me figure out what could be causing this.

```
export const onUserCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {

    const user: User = {
        userId: event.data.uid,
        email: event.data.email
    };

    return db.doc(`users/${user.userId}`).set(data);
});
```

[image]

Comment: I've been unable to duplicate this with any combination of firebase-admin and fireabse-functions libraries.  There might be some transient problem.  In any case, if anyone is seeing this issue, please file a bug with Firebase support with as much information as possible about your setup.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I use the same like below and it works well:

```
exports.onUserCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
   const user = event.data
   console.log(user);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error with Firebase Functions right now and is being [looked into](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/oza-JZMtXlo/Kge4Z0GaCQAJ).

EDIT:

> Hello all, Sebastian from the Firestore SDK team here. We believe this
>   issue is related to the recent update of the GRPC Client SDK and have
>   been running tests with GRPC 1.7.1. So far, we have not been able to
>   reproduce this issue with this older GRPC version.
>
> @google-cloud/firestore is now at 0.10.1. If you update your
>   dependencies, you will be able to pull in this release.
>
> Thanks for your patience.
>
> Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly a permanent answer as this is something Google seems to be looking into.

In the meantime though I did some research on similar error messages across the Google libraries and it looks like it happens occasionally when you initialise a Google library outside of a function (ie. at the top of your file).

I've added this line within the function being executed instead of within the global scope and it looks to have stopped the error:

`const datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')({});`

For example instead of:

```
const datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')({});

module.exports.myFunction = function() {
   datastore.get(key).then()....
}
```

you do

```
module.exports.myFunction = function() {
    const datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')({});
   datastore.get(key).then()....
}
```

That would go for Firebase libraries too – not just datastore. This isn't best-practice and should be changed back when the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out this is a bug in the Firestore Node module. Update @google-cloud/firestore to version 0.10.1 and it should fix the issue.