# "Stream removed" error in Firebase Functions/Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I created a project using firebase, cloud functions and firestore as db, but I am getting "Stream removed" error sporadically. This error happens when I am executing the function bellow:

```
exports.createUser = functions.auth
  .user()
  .onCreate(event => {
    const user = event.data;
    const registrationDate = new Date().getTime();
    const {uid, email, displayName, photoURL} = user;

    const userRelevantInfo = {
      ...
    };

    return usersRef.doc(uid).set(userRelevantInfo);
  });
```

Using "setLogFunction" from firestore, this is what gets logged:

[image: Logs from firestore]

Does anyone knows what is happening or how can I fix this?

Comment: Same issue reported here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/47870711/4815718.  See also: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/oza-JZMtXlo/Kge4Z0GaCQAJ

Comment: Please post text rather than images when at all possible.  Text is searchable and copyable.  Images are not so much.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue the last few days. I reported it to Firebase and they have fixed the issue. Update `@google-cloud/firestore` to version 0.10.1 (just released). This fixed the issue for me.

Admin Node 5.6.0 was also just released, which uses the latest Firestore as well.